# Gradle native c plugin: Add directory with .h/.lib files to look for while compiling

Tags: c, gradle

My gradle build for a native shared library looks like this at the moment:

```
apply plugin: 'c'
apply plugin: 'visual-studio'

model {
  components {     
    main(NativeLibrarySpec) {
      sources.c {
        source {
          srcDirs "src/main/c"
          include "**/*.c"
        }
        exportedHeaders {
          srcDirs "src/main/headers"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I add folder that contains .h and .lib files, which I depend on, so that they are found while compiling / linking? The folder I want to add is stored in LIB_NAME env variable.

Comment: Could you please share an example project?

Comment: The code above is pretty much all you need. Put file `test.c` in `src/main/c` and add the line `# include "test.h"`, where test.h is in a directory somewhere on your system LIB_NAME points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and help from the gradle forum I got what I wanted.
You need to use the `PrebuiltLibraries` specification. See [Gradle examples](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/native-binaries/prebuilt/build.gradle).